# Web sites for historical foreign currency exchange rates and inflation data?

Tags: foreign-exchange, inflation, online-data-source, historical-data, cpi

Say that I'm watching a Swedish movie from the 1970s where a bank gets robbed and the robbers get away with 10 million SEK. I might then like to know how much that corresponds to in U.S. dollars *today*, taking both historical exchange rates and inflation into account.

Does anybody know of a web site that can calculate this kind of information? More generally I would want to be able to enter what currency amount X1 I have in year Y1 and get the corresponding currency amount X2 in year Y2.

Comment: My gut says "try Wolfram Alpha" but somebody who knows it better ought to test the theory and post an actual answer, with example queries, if it can do the job. A Google Docs spreadsheet with some logic and data might also work.

Answer (score 3):

[FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/) *could* do it.  They've got the [exchange rates](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/categories/15), they've got the [inflation rates](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/categories/9) as time series.  They've also got various tools to link it to applications or databases.  They won't, however, answer your exact question directly, a little bit of coding (and thought) is needed.

Here's why it's not uniformly possible to answer such questions: Even given only 2 currencies and 2 dates, you still have the possibility to exchange SEK for USD in year `Y1` and then observe US inflation; or you observe Swedish inflation from year `Y1` till year `Y2` and then exchange SEK for USD.

The outcome might be totally different because inflation differentials won't be priced into forex quotes, whereas interest rate differentials will be (keyword carry trade).

A more thorough (but unbacktested) approach would be to obtain some sort of average over all such possible transactions.  For instance: Do the exchange for every CPI publication, and observe Swedish inflation till then and US inflation from then on.  Of all the USD amounts you end up with take a suitable average.

Comment: I was just planning to write up an answer like this referring to FRED. When it comes to free economic data, as a data source it's hard to beat.